# Como redimensionar imagem para tamanho do container?

Tags: css, imagem, layout-responsivo

Tenho um `div` com 1184x308px e quero que sejam colocadas dentro imagens que são dinâmicas.

Dado que as imagens podem ser carregadas com qualquer dimensão, como as posso ajustar as dimensões do `div`?

Answer (score 7):

Se a imagem for menor que a dimensão do div, a abordagem do `max-width` e do `max-height` não vai funcionar, aí é melhor colocar `width: 100%;` e brincar com o height para poder acertar imagem. Colocar `height: auto;` vai fazer a imagem aumentar a altura proporcionalmente. Se você forçar para `height: 100%;`, a imagem vai ficar desproporcional, mas ocupando toda a altura do div. Mesmo assim, a abordagem do `max-width/height` é bastante indicada também.

Tente recortar as imagens sempre na proporção que você precisa ou defina um `width: auto` e `height: 100%` para fazer a imagem ficar sempre com 100% da altura e largura sempre vai extrapolar o div. Logo, coloque um `overflow: hidden` na div, para ela não mostrar a parte da imagem que irá transbordar da largura.

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Faz o div não aumentar a altura por causa da imagem */
}

img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/80yw8h5b/

Comment: Se quiser você pode criar um *snippet* aqui no StackOverflow mesmo @DiegoEis: [Maiores explicações](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/apresentando-js-css-e-html-execut%c3%a1veis) - É claro, apenas sugestão :)

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.minha-div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
A minha div
<div class="minha-div">
    <img src="http://www.deshow.net/d/file/animal/2009-07/cute-kitten-631-2.jpg">
</div>
```

O truque esta em colocar as dimensões máximas (`max-width`, `max-height`) da imagem para 100% o que faz com que preencham o `div`. Caso as imagens sejam mais pequenas, não são afectadas.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar `background-size: cover`, ela vai ocupar o espaço todo. Se a foto for maior que seu container, vai cortar um pouco a imagem, mas ela não vai ficar distorcida, se for menor, ela vai aumentar e ocupar o espaço todo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

No meu código CSS estava da seguinte forma:

```css
figure.foto-legenda {
    position: relative;
    border:  5px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;

}

figure.foto-legenda img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Depois que mudei para os parâmetros max-widht e max-height, ficou na posição correta sem ultrapassar o container.

Comment: Acredito que você esteja com impressão errada do seja o Stack Overflow. para conhecer mais da cultura do site leia [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Também veja [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387) e [help]. Aproveite e faça o nosso [tour].