# Deixar imagem com a tag <img> proporcional em relação a div

Tags: html, css, css3, imagem

Quero deixar a imagem proporcional dentro da div, mas não estou conseguindo. A única "solução" que achei até agora é de colocar object-fit: cover, mas esse estilo não é compatível com muitos navegadores, então não é interessante.

Usando uma imagem pelo css também resolve, mas no meu caso tem que ser com a tag img mesmo.

A classe da div é post-thumbnail

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/GabrielS0uza/pen/Kamdax)

Desproporcional

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Proporcional

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessas 2 imagens abaixo é possível entender melhor o que eu quero. Cortar a imagem deixando ela proporcional, com um background-image ou um object-fit isso é feito facilmente, mas ainda não descobri como fazer com uma imagem no html sem ter que utilizar o object-fit: cover.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, Arial, Helvetica, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block; 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.noticia-index {
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 880px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.noticia-index:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 880px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
}

.post-thumbnail {
  width: 40%;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

.noticia-index-conteudo {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.noticia-titulo {
  margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.noticia-titulo:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.subtitulo-noticia {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #000;
}

.data-hora-noticia {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #000;
}

.icone-comment img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 180px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.comments {
  position: absolute;
  top: 199px;
  left: 201px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
}

.leia-mais {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-family: Georgia, Arial, Helvetica, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.leia-mais:hover {
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticia-index">
      <a href="pagina-noticia.php"><div class="post-thumbnail"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7AQ4sy8.jpg">
      </div></a>
      <div class="noticia-index-conteudo"><a href="pagina-noticia.php"><h2 class="noticia-titulo">jnjncjsa jscnjsac jcisjacijsi jdjsan jwijcj jwqjcj</h2></a>
      <h4 class="subtitulo-noticia">kjsfjewjf jfefjiewjew nf fnewjf fjnjfew jfnew fewf feijfiwe...</h4>
      <p class="data-hora-noticia">27/12/2016 (14:04)</p>
      <span class="icone-comment"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DJhMZHs.png"></span>
      <span class="comments">1</span>
      <a class="leia-mais" href="pagina-noticia.php">Leia mais...       </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, boa tarde. A imagem já está proporcional ao tamanho da div.post-thumbnail. Poderia ser mais claro quanto a isso? O que exatamente está querendo? Tem algum exemplo?||| OBS.: Apaguei estas propriedades da classe post-thumbnail e ficou na mesma situação: thumbackground-size: cover; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; (Acredito que possa apagar também)
  background-position: center;

Comment: Editei com uma explicação mais clara e coloquei imagens para exemplificar

Comment: Esse link pode ajudar -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52733/como-redimensionar-imagem-para-tamanho-do-container

Comment: Não resolveu, infelizmente

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa noite!

Basta adicionar `overflow: hidden;` à regra `.post-thumbnail`. Como essa regra já tem definido um valor para `height`, você pode alterar em `.post-thumbnail img` o valor de `height` para `100%`. Com isso acredito que terá o efeito desejado.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou

Answer (score -1):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Se ela tiver como background .

Comment: Tem que ser com a tag img no html mesmo, como diz o título e a explicação...